# Can we run multiple splits parallel on a Single node machine?

Tags: hadoop

I am using hadoop on single node machine.When I run a large file with 1GB size and split size is 128MB.So, it runs the file in 8 splits but these splits runs sequentially means one split starts executing after completion of another split. Do we have to set any property value to run the splits parallelly on single node machine.

Answer (score 0):

`Hadoop` provides a distributed processing framework (`batch`), i.e. `MapReduce`, which executes the tasks in parallel. But the level of parallelism depends on number of machines in your cluster. Parallelism can also be controlled with `input split size` but since you have a stand alone setup, the parallelism can not be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for the response..But I have read some where that if we have machine with optimal resources like cores,RAM then we can achieve parallel processing of splits by setting the value of configuration property "mapreduce.job.maps" even we have single node machine but I am not able to configure this property. Is this not correct?

Comment: Can any one help me with this.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. To be frank I am not into Hadoop admin much. But what I can theoretically/logically deduce is this: if we are able to create multiple virtual machines out of a big machine (by dividing CPU, RAM, Cache and HDD), then theoretically, we can have multiple resources available at our disposal. These VMs can then be configured to form a mini Hadoop cluster which should be able to execute things in parallel. This is the same way we create executors by assigning cores and memory in a Spark environment. Personally, I haven't seen this setup before, at least for Hadoop.

Comment: Thank you Rohit... But it did not work for me. Anyone can suggest me what approach I should use

Comment: can anyone help me out

Comment: Add comment to the question, this will make the question active again, thereby, will attract more members.

Comment: @VarinderKumar What Kumar said is correct. But you cannot reasonably split only a single machine. Its still one disk, one network, cpu, RAM, etc. You absolutely need multiple machines (and large files) to achieve fast processing speeds

Comment: After further research, I found that Hadoop guy's have given the support of parallel processing for Local mode as well. I am able to achieve this by using the property "mapreduce.local.map.tasks.maximum". May help for someone else as well.

Comment: But now getting  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error for large files need to increase the heap memory for mapper phase. Anyone can help me with this?